# Render header with /abc/abc/abc php

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I have experience with php but i'm new to the zend frameworks. Could some one please give me some leads as to how I can get a site to work ie- www.facebook.com/nathandoe/photos
.
Using controllers how can i create a function that accepts different names and direct it that page ?

if i have a site www.hello.com/profile

instead of using GET www.hello.com/profile?is=342342?photos

how to handle it as www.hello.com/profile/342342/photos

i have controllers that handle the index and i know how to create different functions .. im stuck with www.hello.com/profile/xxxxxxxx/photos that part

Comment: Have you looked into Zend's routes? That's pretty much what's they're for. You could also use URL rewriting, but I'd suggest sticking with Zend Framework's routing.

Answer (score 1):

In your module/[Module Name]/config/module.config.php, you can set the routes.

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'album' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Something like

```
'route'    => '/profile/[/:id]/photos',
```

Reference http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html